# Filter ID based on 2 conditions

Tags: r, date, group-by, filtering, multiple-conditions

I've created this sample dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), 
                 car = c("subaru", "audi", "subaru", "toyota", "toyota", "audi", "subaru", "nissan", "nissan"),
                buy_date = c("01/01/2000", "01/01/2001", "01/02/2001", "01/01/2000", "01/05/2000", "01/01/2005", "01/03/2005", "01/01/2000", "02/01/2000"))

df$buy_date <- as.Date(df$buy_date, format="%d/%m/%Y") #it doesnt work properly, but that is not the issue atm
```

which produces this df:

| id | car | buy_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | subaru | 2000-01-01 |
| 1 | audi | 2001-01-01 |
| 1 | subaru | 2001-02-01 |
| 2 | toyota | 2000-01-01 |
| 2 | toyota | 2004-12-01 |
| 2 | audi | 2005-01-01 |
| 2 | subaru | 2005-03-01 |
| 3 | nissan | 2000-01-01 |
| 3 | nissan | 2000-01-02 |

And I want filter for the following: For each ID, I wanna keep the rows from the ID if he/she has bought two different type of cars within 180 days. so it should return a list something like this:

| id | car | buy_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | audi | 2001-01-01 |
| 1 | subaru | 2001-02-01 |
| 2 | toyota | 2004-12-01 |
| 2 | audi | 2005-01-01 |
| 2 | subaru | 2005-03-01 |

Hope you can help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with two inner joins. Note that in your example data the second toyota purchased by id #2 does not match the "2004-12-01" date, so I changed it (see Input, below)

```
library(dplyr)

df$buy_date <- as.Date(df$buy_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")

inner_join(
  df, 
  inner_join(df,df,by="id", multiple="all") %>% 
    filter(car.x!=car.y, abs(buy_date.x-buy_date.y)<180) %>% 
    select(id, car=car.x, buy_date=buy_date.x) %>% 
    distinct()
)
```

Output:

```
  id    car   buy_date
1  1   audi 2001-01-01
2  1 subaru 2001-02-01
3  2 toyota 2004-12-01
4  2   audi 2005-01-01
5  2 subaru 2005-03-01
```

Input:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), car = c("subaru", 
"audi", "subaru", "toyota", "toyota", "audi", "subaru", "nissan", 
"nissan"), buy_date = c("01/01/2000", "01/01/2001", "01/02/2001", 
"01/01/2000", "01/12/2004", "01/01/2005", "01/03/2005", "01/01/2000", 
"02/01/2000")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it does the job perfectly!

Comment: So my actual dataframe have around 12.000.000 entries. and I get the following error:
Error in vctrs::vec_locate_matches(needles = needles, haystack = haystack, :
Would you know how to fix it?

Comment: without more information, I can't give you a good answer re that error. However, I can tell you that with 12,000,000 records you definitely don't want to be using `dplyr`.  Switch to data.table and perhaps do a non-equi join

Answer (score 0):

Constructing the conditionals and then `filter`ing

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(dif = c(diff.Date(buy_date), 0) < 180, 
         dup = ifelse(dif, car, NA), .by = id) %>% 
  filter(!(duplicated(dup) | duplicated(dup, fromLast=T) & !is.na(dup)) & 
           dif, .by = id) %>% 
  select(-c(dif, dup))
  id    car   buy_date
1  1   audi 2001-01-01
2  1 subaru 2001-02-01
3  2 toyota 2000-01-01
4  2   audi 2005-01-01
5  2 subaru 2005-03-01
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! Unfortunately I cannot seem to make this code work: 
Error in mutate(., dif = c(diff.Date(buy_date), 0) < 180, dup = if_else(dif, : 

Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `false` must be a character vector,
 not a logical vector.

Comment: Should work now. `if_else` is a little picky.